# Three20 Photo Scroller alternative?

Tags: iphone, slideshow, three20

I wan to add a view in my iPhone app where the user can scroll (paged) through a series of web loaded images.

I've been reading many threads and most of them end up suggesting the Three20 lib. 
I've tried that and looks complicated to integrate and quite heavy in size (1.2Mb added to my app).
Additionally I only need the TTPhotoViewContoller class, but I have to integrate with the whole Three20 bundle.

Is there a lighter solution or component to do a image scroller on iPhone?

Thanks in advance.

Gonso

Comment: I'd also be interested to see if there is an alternative. I'm currently using Three20 in my own apps mainly just for photo viewer, but if I can replace it with something a little less heavy, that'd be great.

Answer (score 14):

Have a look at enormego's PhotoViewer,sounds like it should fit the bill:

"Photo Viewer is the photo viewer from Facebook’s three20 library, torn out, and freed of it’s dependency on three20. We’ve removed most of the bulk code, and it’s weighing in at a lean 800KB vs. three20’s 4.7MB, which is an awful lot for a simple photo viewer."

http://github.com/enormego/PhotoViewer

Comment: Photo Viewer is what I was looking for. However it throws a Warining I can't get rid of, and I'm concern about App Approval: 

"<somePath>/PhotoViewer-Release.fmwk/libPhotoViewer-simulator.a, file is not of required architecture"

Any ideas on how to fix it???

Thanks
Gonso

Comment: It usually means you're trying to use a simulator compiled library on the device, or vice versa. Essentially the library is not a universal binary, containing both arm and i386 architectures. This is something you can fix if you have the source code, by recompiling the library against both SDKs (device and simulator) and using the lipo command line tool to create the universal binary.

Comment: PhotoViewer is no longer the same as the photo viewer from three20 - it's been rewritten from scratch, as the documentation now states. From the [documentation](https://github.com/enormego/PhotoViewer): "EGOPhotoViewer was originally started as a stripped down version of three20's PhotoViewer. We ultimately decided the three20 code base wasn't flexible enough and scrapped the project all together. We rewrote PhotoViewer as EGOPhotoViewer from scratch, based upon our reliable open source libraries EGOCache and EGOImageLoading."

Comment: and so can anyone who has used both three20 and photoviewer give feedback on pros/cons of each?

Answer (score 5):

You might want to take a look at [MWPhotoBrowser](http://github.com/mwaterfall/mwphotobrowser):

MWPhotoBrowser can display one or more images by providing either UIImage objects, or URLs to files, web images or library assets. The photo browser handles the downloading and caching of photos from the web seamlessly. Photos can be zoomed and panned, and optional (customisable) captions can be displayed. The browser can also be used to allow the user to select one or more photos using either the grid or main image view.

[image: MWPhotoBrowser Screenshots]