# display images in fullview in iphone application

Tags: iphone

Im new to iphone development. In my application images are displayed but when i  click one image it was not displaying full view and automaticaly go back to image.I tried but full view not displaying.

can any one plz send me code for image full view and automaticaly go back to images.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great open source project that should solve your problem, and yes it's **not** called three20, check this post's answer: [Three20 Photo Scroller alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973229/three20-photo-scroller-alternative)

Comment: I want to display images in fullview and automaticaly go back to images without using IB.I have to show in programmaticaly in iphone application.Can u plz give me code for images full view.

Comment: dude if you take a close look at the post's answer I was referring to, there is the source code, **https://github.com/enormego/PhotoViewer**